# How to Maintain a variable in Windows Phone

Tags: xml, xaml, windows-phone

I'm doing a small application to display some information read from an XML file. The information is simple only contains the Info, ID and Rate it has and it's kept in a repository

```
static XmlJokeRepository()
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("FactsXML.xml");

        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Joke")
                   select new Jokes
                   {
                       ID = (int)query.Element("ID"),
                       Rate = (int)query.Element("Rate"),
                       Info = (string)query.Element("Info"),

                   };
        countryList = data.ToList();
    }

    public IList<Jokes> GetCountryList()
    {

        return countryList;
    }


    public Jokes GetCountryById(int id)
    {

        return countryList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);
    }
```

Where I have a class that maintains the properties and are kept in a class named Jokes.

```
  public class Jokes
{

    public int Rate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Info
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
  }
}


  interface JokeRepository
 {
     IList<Jokes> GetCountryList();
     Jokes GetCountryById(int id);
  }
```

where I call and load this XML, etc on the MainPage using this
     InitializeComponent();
            JokeRepository countryRepository = new XmlJokeRepository();
            DataContext = countryRepository.GetCountryById(1);

But for it to work I have to actually specify which one do I want to display, instead of just returning the list and managing it from there to be able like for example if the user clicks Next, to get the Next joke or something. I'm looking for a more generic way to do this and get the next joke that I want like form the list and do a simple GetNext().

Also, in the XML I just have the Binding Joke in the textblock. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just added an private IList<Jokes> data and sent a list back to that and it did the job, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be better to load the data in your App startup code (in App.cs) once, and then just access the Current Joke or call a method to Set CurrentJoke to the NextOne()?

You could then use the OnNavigatedTo() event to cycle the Joke.

Let me know if you want an example in code of what I am describing here.